# Cannot deploy Spring Boot exploded artifact using IntelliJ

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, spring-boot

Error appearing during artifact deployment. The `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\logs\catalina.log` doesn't have any information. There are no useful information in IntelliJ's debug console but:

```
Connected to server
[2015-01-24 10:05:18,950] Artifact war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
jaan 24, 2015 10:05:19 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(C:\exploded\WEB-INF\lib\tomcat-embed-el-7.0.55.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/el/Expression.class
jaan 24, 2015 10:05:23 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath: [go.Application@2569b61e]

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.1.6.RELEASE)

[2015-01-24 10:05:29,195] Artifact war exploded: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details
```

What logs should I check?

Answer (score 0):

You've got embedded Tomcat packaged inside your war file which the Tomcat that you're deploying the war to doesn't like. You need to declare the embedded Tomcat dependency as provided. That'll look something like this if you're using Maven:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <!-- ... -->
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <!-- ... -->
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- ... -->
    </dependencies>
</project>
```